# Saving data to a file, in matlab

Tags: arrays, file, matlab, input

I have several numerical arrays and i want to write them to the file in a certain way. I used the following code:

```
file=fopen('d:\file.txt','w');
for i=1:3
fprintf(file, '%6.4e\t%6.4e\r\n', a(i), b(i));
end
```

But it doesn't work. I have an error:

```
Error using fprintf
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file
identifier.
```

What does it mean?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you look through the Matlab documentation for `Simple File I/O`.

Comment: and `output conversions`. Digging through the documentation with those terms you will come across methods that might turn out to be a lot more convenient.

Comment: @SergeiSokolov That code runs fine on my system (R2012b, Linux Mint v12). The only thing I changed was the file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Octave (which has very similar syntax to Matlab) you can do

```
function wfile()

    a = [1;2;3];
    b = [10; 20; 30];

    file=fopen('file.txt','w');
    for i=1:3
        line_to_write = sprintf('%d and %d\r\n', a(i), b(i));
        fprintf(file, line_to_write);
    end
    fclose(file);
end
```

The path `d:\` might be better set using `pwd = d:\`